# npm install fails with npm.cmd: command not found

Tags: linux, npm, npm-install, nvm, n

We currently do `sudo npm i` instead of `npm i` to circumvent this issue. Our Ubuntu team members can't do this however because nvm isn't installed for root. NVM and N both have this same issue.

```
geoyws-mbp:ifca-construction-react geoyws$ npm i

> ifca-construction-react@0.1.0 prepare /Users/geoyws/work/src/ifca/ifca-react/src/modules/ifca-construction-react
> npm.cmd run compile

sh: npm.cmd: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! ifca-construction-react@0.1.0 prepare: `npm.cmd run compile`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ifca-construction-react@0.1.0 prepare script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/geoyws/.npm/_logs/2019-10-03T09_40_46_545Z-debug.log
```

[image]

Comment: *A complete log of this run can be found in... "* - You should examine the log file and provide the details.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that one of our engineers changed our `npm` start script from `npm run compile` to `npm.cmd run compile` in our `package.json`. Either that or create-react-app did that, which is very unwise because people work with various OSes on the same codebase.